# Implement LMI constraint with CVXPY

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

So I am trying to implement a simple optimization code in Python using the CVXPY package (an optimization problem with a linear matrix inequality constraint). The code is show below.

I have tried running the code using Python 3.6.

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import control as cs

gamma = cp.Variable();
MAT1 = np.array([[1, gamma], [1+gamma, 3]])

constraints_2 = [MAT1 >> 0]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(gamma),constraints_2)
prob.solve()
```

Every time I try to run this code, I get the following error:

*"Non-square matrix in positive definite constraint."*

But the matrix is clearly square! So I don't know what is happening.
Any ideas? 
Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45730523/6338725

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MAT1` is a numpy array, you'll need to make it a cvxpy Variable to use the semidefinite constraint. Try this:

```
MAT1 = cp.Variable((2, 2))
constraints_2 = [MAT1 >> 0, MAT1[0, 0] == 1, MAT1[1, 0] == 1 + MAT1[0, 1], MAT1[1, 1] == 3]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(MAT1[0, 1]), constraints_2)
```

`gamma` is then about `-2.73`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. But is this the best way to model all LMI's with affine variables? What if instead you have like 10 variables (gamma_1, gamma_2, etc...).

Comment: If you need to impose structure on the matrix as a whole (like semidefinite) and have structure of the variables within the matrix, I don't know of a simpler way (not to say it doesn't exist). You could probably make the code more readable than what I've presented here.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I think I will repost a question for a more complicated problem, and see how it can be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

There is a technical and a conceptual problem here

### Tecnical problem

The problem is that your MAT1 is not a `numpy` array

You could have written

```py
MAT1=cvxpy.vstack([cvxpy.hstack([1 , gamma]), cvxpy.hstack([1+gamma, 3])])
```

Or more concisely

```py
MAT1=cvxpy.vstack([cvxpy.hstack([1 , gamma]), cvxpy.hstack([1+gamma, 3])])
```

This way the `cvxpy` will accept your code, but will not give the correct answer.

### Conceptual problem

The SDP problems are convex only for symmetric matrices, what `cvxpy` will do is to make it symmetric (apparently by adding it to it's transpose). The solution given is the minimum `gamma` such that `[[1, 0.5+gamma], [0.5+gamma, 3]] >> 0`.